# Getting the URL address from an IFrame on my site with PHP

Tags: iframe

I have a simple IFrame of another site in my site:

```
     <iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.walla.co.il" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
```

That site doesn't belong to me in any way. I was looking for way go get the exact URL address
of that site and post it as an echo so viewers could see the address of that site on my site.
I found some scripts online but they didnt seem to work.

Is it even possible to do it? I am just looking for a way to echo it a variable (something like echo $url;)

This is what i've tried so far:

```
    <iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.walla.co.il" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>

    <?php
    $htmlPage = file_get_contents("http://www.walla.co.il"); //the page has the iframe

    if(preg_match_all("/<iframe[^>]*name=\"frame1\"[^>]*src=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>/i", $htmlPage, $matches))
    {
        print_r($matches);
        echo $matches[1][0];
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do that:

```
$htmlPage = '<iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.walla.co.il" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>'; //the page has the iframe

if(preg_match_all("/<iframe[^>]*name=\"frame1\"[^>]*src=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>/i", $htmlPage, $matches))
{
    //print_r($matches);
    echo $matches[1][0];
}
```

this is not tested though...

Edit: I don't know what are you trying to accomplish in here but you can't do it like that.
the html string of the iframe should be inside a variable. something like see the updated answer...

Comment: it works with "<iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.walla.co.il" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>"

Comment: @user1938653 - Are you getting any errors? try to uncomment print_r statement. and see the result of the array

Comment: No errors, I just can't see the echo on my website. Edit your answer, I don't know what you meant when you said: it works with "<iframe name="frame1" src="walla.co.il"; width="100%" height="400"></iframe>"

Comment: means the html code you posted is matched with the regex pattern that I wrote. if the name tag of the iframe is different please update the pattern with the original name

Comment: I updated my question, scroll up and see exactly what I did. I just can't see the echo, but the Iframe works.